# Cannot upload document into AWS CloudSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm using AWS CloudSearch SDK Java (aws-java-sdk-cloudsearch 1.11.288)to upload document to CloudSearch. But it throws this exception:

```
AmazonCloudSearchDomainException: null (Service: AmazonCloudSearchDomain; Status Code: 411; Error Code: null...
```

Still not find the solution for that issue. I can upload the same json data using AWS Cloudsearch CLI.
How can I get over this exception?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/documents-batch-resource.html) says that a request to upload documents will receive a response with the 411 status code when it is missing the Content-Length header.

Make sure to set the content length by calling the [setContentLength()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudsearchdomain/model/UploadDocumentsRequest.html#setContentLength-java.lang.Long-) method on the UploadDocumentsRequest object with the appropriate value for your request.